# Extracting data from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is to write a SQL query to return the names of all teachers who have taught a course where at least 2 students received a `B-` or better in the course.

My tables are:

```
Courses(id, name, teacher_id)
Grades(student_id, course_id, grade)
Students(id, name, email, password)
Teachers(id, name)
```

I used the following query:

`SELECT * FROM grades JOIN teachers WHERE grades.grade = 'B-'`

But shows all teacher like

[image]

Comment: It would probably be easier to use numerical values for the grades than varchars. `85-89` is easier to account for programmatically than `b-`, or `b`.

Comment: I think that's the way it should be stored, as varchars. 85-89 should be computed on client, but not stored on database, the resulting grade is the purpose

Answer (score 2):

You can use exists() for that to check if for each teacher exists a course that had more then 2 'b-' or better

So your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Teachers t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT c.teacher_id from Courses c
             inner join grades g ON c.id= g.course_id
             where t.id = c.teacher_id and g.grade in('B-','B','A-','A','A+')
             group by c.teacher_id having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select distinct Teachers.name from Courses join Teachers on Courses.teacher_id = Teachers.id where Courses.id in (Select course_id from (Select course_id, count(student_id) as 'total' from Grades where grade = 'B-' or grade = 'B' or grade = 'B+' or grade = 'A-' or grade = 'A' group by course_id) a where a.total > 1)
```

Comment: The 2 queries are not necessarily , you can you having count(*) >1 instead of wrapping it with another query and using a where clause, further more, if a teacher taught in more then two courses that had more the two students, he will be returned twice or more. And lastly, use IN(v1,v2,v3) instead of OR's which will slow the process.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it almost immediately after posting; I realized that I only had B-. Now it will include "or better".

Comment: @sagi Good point. I didn't think about duplicate Teachers. I will edit. I believe you about having count(*) > 1 in the where clause, but I've never tested that, so I will leave that bit as a way I know will work.

Comment: Having clause is like a where clause to a group by , so when you use group by, if you want to have where on one of the aggregated values, you need to use having clause after the group by. E.G. look at my solution